# When i run my program.exe six times open new windows (PYQT5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, progress-bar, pyinstaller, spyder

My program is pdf file compressing firstly convert pdf to image and resize this image and finally convert image to pdf. When i compile this code in Spyder. Program is run correctly but i convert to exe using pyinstaller and choosing mid quality or low quaility and press compress button six times open new window.  i did not solve this problem. Actually what i want ask a question. Why do not program.exe run correctly just like when run correctly compile in Spyder?

Please run and convert to exe this codes in your pc tell me whether run correctly!

Thanks in advance

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QProgressBar, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QDialog, QMessageBox, QStatusBar
import time
import os.path
import sys
import pypdfium2 as pdfium 

class Ui_Pdf_compress(object):
    def setupUi(self, Pdf_compress):
        Pdf_compress.setObjectName("Pdf_compress")
        Pdf_compress.resize(353, 242)
        Pdf_compress.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(353, 242))
        Pdf_compress.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(353, 242))
        Pdf_compress.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('1.ico'))
        flags = Qt.WindowFlags()
        Pdf_compress.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.Upload = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Pdf_compress)
        self.Upload.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 40, 112, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Upload.setFont(font)
        self.Upload.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.Upload.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 253, 222);")
        self.Upload.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.Upload.setDefault(False)
        self.Upload.setFlat(False)
        self.Upload.setObjectName("Upload")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Pdf_compress)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 171, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.lineEdit.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.lineEdit.setFrame(True)
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Pdf_compress)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 171, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.comboBox.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("\n"
"")
        self.comboBox.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.compress_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Pdf_compress)
        self.compress_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 110, 112, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.compress_button.setFont(font)
        self.compress_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.compress_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 255);")
        self.compress_button.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.compress_button.setObjectName("compress_button")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Pdf_compress)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 131, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Pdf_compress)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(254, 225, 101, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Pdf_compress)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 240, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.retranslateUi(Pdf_compress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Pdf_compress)
    def retranslateUi(self, Pdf_compress):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Pdf_compress.setWindowTitle(_translate("Pdf_compress", "PDF Compress"))
        self.Upload.setText(_translate("Pdf_compress", "Upload PDF"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Pdf_compress", "Middle Quality"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Pdf_compress", "Low Quality"))
        self.compress_button.setText(_translate("Pdf_compress", "Compress"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Pdf_compress", "Quality Options:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Pdf_compress", "Created by Resul"))
        self.Upload.clicked.connect(self.upload_pdf)
        self.compress_button.clicked.connect(self.press_pdf)
        
    def show_info_messagebox_1(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)  
        # setting message for Message Box
        msg.setText("---  PDF is compressed  --- ")        
        # setting Message box window title
        msg.setWindowTitle("  SUCCESSFULLY  ")     
        # declaring buttons on Message Box
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        # start the app
        retval = msg.exec_()
    def show_info_messagebox(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)  
        msg.setText("---  PLease choose a pdf file  --- ")        
        msg.setWindowTitle("  WARNING  ")     
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        retval = msg.exec_()
    def show_critical_messagebox(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        msg.setText("!!!   PDF file could not be compressed   !!!")
        msg.setWindowTitle("!!!  ERROR  !!!")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        retval = msg.exec_()
    def upload_pdf(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None ,"Open a file", "",
                                            "*pdf")
        file = fileName[0]
        self.lineEdit.setText(file)    
    def press_pdf(self):
        file= self.lineEdit.text()
        if file == "":
            self.show_info_messagebox()
        if self.comboBox.currentText()== "Middle Quality" and file!= "":
            size = (600,720)
        if self.comboBox.currentText()== "Low Quality" and file!= "":
            size = (450,600)
        image_list=[]
        if file!= "" :
            try:        
                pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(file)
                # convert pdt to image
                page_indices = [i for i in range(len(pdf))]
                renderer = pdf.render_to(
                    pdfium.BitmapConv.pil_image,
                    page_indices = page_indices)
                self.pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Pdf_compress)
                self.pbar.setVisible(True)
                self.label_3.setText("Please wait PDF is compressing...")
                self.pbar.setGeometry(20, 180, 311, 23)
                for image, index in zip(renderer, page_indices):
                    percent = float((100*index)/len(page_indices))
                    percent=round(percent,2)
                    self.pbar.setValue(percent)
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    # resie image files
                    image = image.resize(size)
                    image.convert('RGB')
                    image_list.append(image)
                # convert image to pdf
                image_list[0].save(file.replace('.pdf','_pressed.pdf'), save_all=True, append_images=image_list[1:])
                image.close()
                pdf.close()         
            except:
                     
                     self.show_critical_messagebox()
                     self.lineEdit.clear()
                     self.label_3.clear()
                     self.pbar.setVisible(False)
            else:
                     
                     self.pbar.setValue(100)
                     self.show_info_messagebox_1()
                     self.lineEdit.clear()
                     self.label_3.clear()
                     self.pbar.setVisible(False)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Pdf_compress = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Pdf_compress()
    ui.setupUi(Pdf_compress)
    Pdf_compress.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "six times open window": what window? Also: 1. you're not expected to edit pyuic files (follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); 2. do *not* use blocking function like `time.sleep`; 3. use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 4. provide a [mre] (emphasis on **minimal**).

Comment: 1- Window is user interface  (Main Window)

Comment: Actually what i want ask a question. Why do not program.exe run correctly just like when run correctly compile in Spyder? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that when you press the button, you get **6 new windows**? Please [edit] your question and show the command/configuration you use to create the exe with pyinstaller.

Comment: Yes i get 6 new windows. pyinstaller program_name.py --onefile

Comment: and i try auto-py-to-exe unfourtanetly i get same result

Comment: I think reveal this problem because of pdfium2 library

Comment: Then I suggest you to contact the maintainers of that project

Comment: I'm the author of pypdfium2 and received a mail from the reporter linking this post. As others have already hinted at, the question is extremely vague and lacks a minimal reproducible example. From what I can guess, however, the issue is not caused by pypdfium2 in any way. I believe this is purely an issue with the reporter's own code.

Comment: @mara004  It isn't  I was able to compile the OP's code fine using pypdfium2.  I had already mentioned this earlier but my comment mus have been removed

Comment: Have anyone try my code ?

Comment: @mara004 Had a similar problem as OP. I think I was able to locate the reason. In the pypdfium2\_helpers\document.py file, the render_to function has a parameter n_processes which is set to a default value of os.cpu_count(). This caused my main program to trigger multiple times too. When I did an override of the value of n_processes to 1, I got one additional new instance of the program instead of many. The program runs fine from VSCode, but when I package it using pyinstaller, I get the issue. Not sure how to address it. :|

Comment: @Neodawn Oh, that's interesting. Thank you for reporting this. pypdfium2's multi-page renderer uses a ProcessPoolExecutor to render pages in parallel, which is faster. Apparently the spawning of new processes causes issues with PyInstaller, which should be reported there. In the meantime, note that you can also render on page level without multiprocessing.

Comment: @Neodawn: Can you please check if adding a call to multiprocessing.freeze_support() at the start of your program fixes the issue? (see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6852#issuecomment-1138269358)

Comment: @mara004 Thanks a lot. adding multiprocessing.freeze_support() helped address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

pypdfium2's `PdfDocument.render()` method is a multi-page renderer backed by a process pool. With PyInstaller, the spawning of a new process would launch a new instance of your app, so *your code* needs to be protected with a call to [`multiprocessing.freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) right at the start of your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block to prevent this.

See also https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6852#issuecomment-1138269358